# jQuery times out waiting for server to respond back

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Background:

- I have two pages (index.php and script.php).
- I have a jQuery function that calls script.php from index.php.
- script.php will do a ton of data processing and then return that data back to index.php so that it can be displayed to the user.

Problem:

- index.php appears to be timing out because script.php is taking to long to finish. script.php can sometimes take up to 4 hrs to finish processing before it can return the data to index.php.
- the reason I say index.php is timing out is b/c it never updates and just sits there with an hour glass even after script.php stops processing.
- i know for sure that script.php does finish processing successfully b/c i'm writing the output to a log file as well and see that everything is being processed.
- if there is not much data to be processed by script.php then index.php will update as it is supposed to.
- I'm not setting any timeout values within the function inside index.php when calling script.php.

Is there a better to get index.php to update after waiting a very long time for script.php to finish? I'm using FireFox, so is it maybe a FireFox issue?

Comment: Is splitting up your script in several steps not an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you seriously want an ajax call to take four hours to respond?  That makes little sense in the normal way the web and browsers work.  I'd strongly suggest a redesign.

That said, jQuery's `$.ajax()` call has a timeout value you can set as an option described here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.  I have no idea if the browser will allow it to be set as long as four hours and still operate properly.  In any case, it's not a high probability operation to require keeping a browser connection open and live for four hours.  If there's a momentary hiccup, what are you going to do?  start all over again?  This is just not a good design.

What I would suggest as a redesign is that you break the problem up into smaller pieces that can be satisfied in much shorter ajax calls.  If you really want a four hour operation, then I'd suggest you start the operation with one ajax call and then you poll every few minutes from the browser to inquire when the job is done.  When it is finally done, then you can retrieve the results. This would be much more compatible with the normal way that ajax calls and browsers work and it wouldn't suffer if there is a momentary internet glitch during the four hours.

If possible, your first ajax call could also return an approximation for how long the operation might take which could provide some helpful UI in the browser that is waiting for the results.

Here's a possibility:

Step 1.  Send ajax call requesting that the job start.  Immediately receive back a job ID and any relevant information about the estimated time for the job.

Step 2.  Calculate a polling interval based on the estimated time for the job.  If the estimate is four hours and the estimates are generally accurate, then you can set a timer and ask again in two hours.  When asking for the data, you send the job ID returned by the first ajax call.

Step 3.  As you near the estimated time of completion, you can narrow the polling interval down to perhaps a few minutes.  Eventually, you will get a polling request that says the data is done and it returns the data to you.  If I was designing the server, I'd cache the data on the server for some period of time in case the client has to request it again for any reason so you don't have to repeat the four hour process.

---

Oh, and then I'd think about changing the design on my server so that nothing that is requested regularly every takes four hours.  It should either be pre-built and pre-cached in some sort of batch fashion (e.g. a couple times a day) or the whole scheme should be redone so that common queries can be satisfied in less than a minute rather than four hours.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I definitely need to re-think and re-design.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to periodically send a response back to index.php just to "keep it alive" ? If not, perhaps split up your script into a few smaller scripts, and run them in chunks of an hour at a type as opposed to the 4 hours you mentioned above.